# mistake removed insserv ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux

of a mistake I unistalled from my virtualbox and ubuntu insserv
by

```
apt-get remove insserv
```

now is my network down.

is there any way of solve this?

Thank you in advance

Regards

Comment: Check if you find the deb in /var/cache/apt/archives,  if so, reinstall it with `dpkg -i ...`.

Comment: What if not possible? :)

Comment: Since you have access to the internet, download a deb from Ubuntu and store it in a folder that you share with your virtualbox client.   As an alternative, can't you start your network manually?  Eg. `ifup eth0` ?

Comment: no since I have no access to internet I am not able to download a deb.. though I could do it through the machine and then transfer the deb file to the virtual-machine. though I have no idea which deb file I need to use  I googled a lots on insserv, though I only get init scripts.

Comment: Select your platform and mirror here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/insserv

Comment: Thank you I will do that.

notice is the same package for Kali-linux I guess? though it builds on debian 8.

Comment: Sorry Daniël, no experience with Ubuntu nor Kali.

Comment: Thank you I believe there is a alternative as deb for Kali anyhow and thank you a lot!

Comment: OK, I'll add this as an answer.  If you would be so kind to accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have access to the internet, download a deb from Ubuntu (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/insserv) and store it in a folder that you share with your virtualbox client.

Comment: I let you know once I have tested.